# Using takeUntil in each pipe is a redundant step?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I just wonder if using `takeUntil` in each pipe is the best practice or only one for the whole?

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
text$.pipe(
  debounceTime(200),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  filter((term) => term.length >= 2),
  tap(() => (this.searching = true)),
  switchMap((term) =>
    this.searchService.search(term).pipe(
      catchError(() => {
        this.searchFailed = true;
        return of([]);
      }),
      takeUntil(this._destroy$)
    )
  ),
  tap(() => (this.searching = false)),
  takeUntil(this._destroy$)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it depends on what you want to achieve.

If you only use the last `takeUntil`, when its observable emits, the entire stream will be unsubscribed.

If you only use the `takeUntil` from `switchMap`'s callback, then if it emits, only the `switchMap`'s inner observable will be unsubscribed, but not the entire stream.

So, if you want the entire stream to be unsubscribed, just place a `takeUntil` at the end of the *main*(outer) stream. But if you want a specific inner observable to complete only when a specific observable emits, you'll have to add `takeUntil` *only* there.